# Why does Google Pinyin Input need to access my contacts?

Tags: security, input-methods

A pop-up message says that Google Pinyin Input tries to access my contacts.  Does anyone know why an input method needs to access a user's contacts?
It is strange that this message popped up when I was **NOT** using the input method. I have never used it.  The app was installed by default on a tablet made in China.
Does anyone know if Google Pinyin Input is developed by Google's own engineers or outsourced to a certain country?  I will immediately uninstall it if it is effectively an app developed by a third party in a certain country other than Google's own staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually keyboard apps want to access your contacts for "predictive search" and auto-correction. If you don't like that, it should be fine to reject that request (and thus not giving them access) – without any "harm" to the app. Only it then won't know your contacts' names and cannot use them for auto-correction and "predictive search", of course.

That the request popped up while you were not even using the app might also be normal: depending on how it was programmed, it might want to update its dictionary while not being actively used. That it does so when you've *never ever* used it, is either bad programming or intentional bad habit (of course seen as a service to you, as it's always the case with pre-installed [bloatware](/questions/tagged/bloatware)).

If this worries you, you can go to *Settings › Apps,* switch to the "All" tab (to show all apps, including the pre-installed ones), scroll to the app, tap its entry, and see if you can uninstall or at least [disable](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/disable-app/info) it.